# How to count occurrences of a phrase in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have an array:

```
ABC
GHI
XYZ
ABC
GHI
DEF
MNO
XYZ
```

How can I count the occurrences of each phrase in this array?

(Can I use a for loop?)

Expected output:

```
2 ABC
1 DEF
2 GHI
1 MNO
2 XYZ
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pure `bash` and an associative array to hold the counts:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a words=(ABC GHI XYZ ABC GHI DEF MNO XYZ) # regular array
declare -A counts # associative array

# Count how many times each element of words appears
for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    counts[$word]=$(( ${counts[$word]:-0} + 1 ))
done

# Order of output will vary
for word in "${!counts[@]}"; do
    printf "%d %s\n" "${counts[$word]}" "$word"
done
```

Comment: There's also the `+1` trick: `counts[$word]=$(( ${counts[$word]} +1 ))`

Comment: @Fravadona I prefer the explicit 0 if the element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: `declare -Ai counts` … `((++counts["$word"]))` There is no need to care whether the element exists or not.

Comment: @Shawn `man bash` > `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` > `A null value evaluates to 0.` Eg: `declare -A aa; echo $(()) $((  )) $((aa[no such]))
` gives `0 0 0`. You can do it like this anyway: `for i in words; do ((++counts[$i])); done`. (the formatting is a bit rough here, but you get the drift)

Comment: @dan I prefer the explicit 0 if the element doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

`sort file.txt | uniq -c` should do the job.

If you mean an array in bash, echo them:

```
array=(ABC GHI XYZ ABC GHI DEF MNO XYZ)
for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
  2 ABC
  1 DEF
  2 GHI
  1 MNO
  2 XYZ
```

Comment: A bit shorter version: `array=(ABC GHI XYZ ABC GHI DEF MNO XYZ); IFS=$'\n'; (sort | uniq -c) <<< ${array[*]}`